# ADT does not recognize a device while operating system does

Tags: android, adb, adt, linux-mint

Excuse me if this is off-topic or has been answered in another thread, but I could not find a solution.

I have a BQ Edison 2 QC tablet (Spanish brand: [[http://www.bqreaders.com/productos/edison-2-quad-core.html]](http://www.bqreaders.com/productos/edison-2-quad-core.html%5d)). When I connect it with an USB cable, I can see it in my desktop and I can transfer files normally from the operating system, but Eclipse/ADT does not see it. I am developing an Android app and I can not install it on this device.

- I am runnig Linux Mint Debian Edition, and it is up to date.
- When I connect another device (Nexus 7 or Samsung Galaxy II), Eclipse/ADT does see it and I can launch my application on either.
- I have activated the developer options and the USB developing in the tablet.
- I tried to install android-tools-adb and edited /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules, including a line with SYSFS{idVendor}=="2207", having obtained 2207 from lsusb for my tablet (and rebooted, etc). Anyway, this adb package is not needed to recognize my other android devices from the ADT, so I have uninstalled it again. The eclipse environment starts its own copy of adb contained into [adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321]/sdk/platform-tools. I don't know where does it store the vendor ID's, because /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules didn't exist before and it was working for my Nexus and Galaxy devices.

Thanks a lot in advance to whoever might help me!!!

Comment: A simple check involves `adb kill-server; sudo adb devices`. If your device show up this way, the issue is with **udev** rules. Else, you have some other problem. If you have a Mac around, you can try to plug  the tablet into it, just to check. Also, try to delete `$HOME/.android` - maybe, some old keys interfere with the new device.

Comment: I tried to restart adb but nothing happened. Finally, I followed the instructions in one post I found, and created a file called adb_usb.ini under ~/.android directory whose content is 0x2207 (the vendor ID of the tablet). When I restarted adb AFTER creating this file, at last it showed my tablet. Still, I needed to unconect a connect again for it to turn online and appear as an eligible target for Eclipse. Thank you very much, anyway.

Comment: I think it would be polite to provide a link to http://android.stackexchange.com/a/48244/22992

Comment: For sure. That post would have solved my problem, but I couldn't find it. Instead, I read the information from this site: http://www.htcmania.com/showthread.php?t=387623

Comment: At any rate, when you find something useful - please link it!

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled developer options?? It can be found in settings. And dont forget to check usb debugging.

Comment: Yes, I did. I followed all the steps I had to for debugging into the Nexus 7 and the Galaxy 2, but Eclipse/ADT does not see this tablet, while the Operating system sees it and transfers files normally.